# Java - JPA/Hibernate: "MappingException: Could not determine type"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, h2

I am new to Java / Spring / Hibernate and I am building a small test project for a hypothetical courier service.
I am now trying to implement a database using javax.persistance/hibernate but I get an error when trying to run the project:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: courier.order.OrderState, at table: order, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(accepted_state)]
```

Here is my code for the `Order`-class. It implements the State Design Pattern through the `OrderState`-interface.

```
package courier.order;

import courier.states.*;

import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
public class Order implements OrderState{

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String deliverer;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String customer;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String customerStreet;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String customerNumber;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String customerZip;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String deliveree;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String deliverStreet;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String deliverNumber;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String deliverZip;


    //attribute-setters

    public void setDeliverer(String newDeliverer){
        deliverer = newDeliverer;
    }
    public void setCustomer(String newCustomer){
        customer = newCustomer;
    }
    public void setCustomerStreet(String newCustomerStreet){
        customerStreet = newCustomerStreet;
    }
    public void setCustomerNumber(String newCustomerNumber){
        customerNumber = newCustomerNumber;
    }
    public void setCustomerZip(String newCustomerZip){
        customerZip = newCustomerZip;
    }
    public void setDeliveree(String newDeliveree){
        deliveree = newDeliveree;
    }
    public void setDeliverStreet(String newDeliverStreet){
        deliverStreet = newDeliverStreet;
    }
    public void setDeliverNumber(String newDeliverNumber){
        deliverNumber = newDeliverNumber;
    }
    public void setDeliverZip(String newDeliverZip){
        deliverZip = newDeliverZip;
    }

    //attribute-getter

    public String getDeliverer(){
        return deliverer;
    }
    public String getCustomer(){
        return customer;
    }
    public String getCustomerStreet(){
        return customerStreet;
    }
    public String getCustomerNumber(){
        return customerNumber;
    }
    public String getCustomerZip(){
        return customerZip;
    }
    public String getDeliveree(){
        return deliveree;
    }
    public String getDeliverStreet(){
        return deliverStreet;
    }
    public String getDeliverNumber(){
        return deliverNumber;
    }
    public String getDeliverZip(){
        return deliverZip;
    }

    //define states
    OrderState newState;
    OrderState acceptedState;
    OrderState inDeliveryState;
    OrderState deliveredState;
    OrderState canceledState;

    //saved state
    OrderState orderState;

    //constructor
    public Order() {
        //initialize states
        newState = new NewState(this);
        acceptedState = new AcceptedState(this);
        inDeliveryState = new InDeliveryState(this);
        deliveredState = new DeliveredState(this);
        canceledState = new CanceledState(this);

        //Initial state
        orderState = newState;
    }


    //State - getter
    public OrderState getNewState() { return newState; }
    public OrderState getAcceptedState() { return acceptedState; }
    public OrderState getInDeliveryState() { return inDeliveryState; }
    public OrderState getDeliveredState() { return deliveredState; }
    public OrderState getCanceledState() { return canceledState; }

    //State - setter
    public void setOrderState(OrderState newOrderState) {
        orderState = newOrderState;
    }

    //methods
    public void newOrder() {
        setOrderState(newState);
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return orderState.getStatus();
    }

    public void nextStatus() {
        orderState.nextStatus();
    }

    public void cancelOrder() {
        orderState.cancelOrder();
    }

}
```

OrderState interface:

```
package courier.order;

public interface OrderState {

    public String getStatus();
    public void nextStatus();
    public void cancelOrder();

}
```

One of the States, the others ones are build just the same way:

```
package courier.order.states;

import courier.order.Order;
import courier.order.OrderState;

public class AcceptedState implements OrderState {

    Order orderState;

    public AcceptedState(Order newState){
        orderState = newState;
    }


    @Override
    public String getStatus() {
        return "The order was accepted and is being collected by a deliverer.";
    }

    @Override
    public void nextStatus() {
        orderState.setOrderState(orderState.getInDeliveryState());
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelOrder() {

    }
}
```

The code runs flawlessly when I comment out the `@Entity`-annotation

Comment: It looks like it is a design flaw. I would recommend you to avoid using `OrderState` interface

Comment: thanks for the reply! what do you mean by desig flow? is there a problem with implemanting an interface and creating a JPA entity?

Comment: First of all, it is uncommon to have Interface for Entity class. Also, another implementation of this interface (AcceptedState) is not Entity at all. Next, OrderState contains order states. Moreover, nested order states are not marked by any annotations. I would recommend to think on model structure and try to keep it flat (without nested entities) and avoid unnecessary Interface usage

Comment: Don't call your entity "order". Order is a sql keyword and can give you some strange error messages. You could define a concrete table name like "t_order" in an @Table annotation

Comment: Interfaces are not only uncommon for Entities they are even not allowed!